# LIBOR Rates available in CSV, XML etc

Tags: interest-rates, programming, libor

Is there a website that offers current LIBOR rates for all tenors for free in machine readable formats?

Comment: The [BBA provides historical rates](http://www.bbalibor.com/rates/historical) on a two-month delay for personal (non-commercial) use. For what you want, you'll need to get a license, or get the data from authorized vendor. (I notice [this site](http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx) has rates, though I can't see an easy download option.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a little what you mean by "current" but the CDS market developed a "[standardized model](http://www.cdsmodel.com)" for transforming between upfront and spread-based quotes.  The model depends on an agreed curve of risk-free rates.

The LIBOR rates used for CDS settlement are available at:

https://www.markit.com/news/InterestRates_CCY_yyyymmdd.zip

This is not up-to-the minute, so maybe it's too slow for you.  I'm not sure what the terms of service are, but they must be reasonably liberal in order to allow the industry to trade off them.